# How to use localize and i18n on client side

Tags: localization, frontend, react-i18next, lokalise

I want to use localization from lokalise on my front-end project. But I don't like manually downloading files from Lokalise every time.

In Lokalise API I can get url to my localization file, but I don't see an option to use just the link in I18n. It seems I need to deploy a server to serve localization. Is there some possibility to use I18n with Lokalise like with locize: i18next-locize-backend. Or maybe there are another solutions?

Comment: using i18next, I would consider to support the i18next creators by using their locize offering: https://locize.com/i18next.html

Comment: Its impossible by requirements